# How to get displayname attribute value from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an DisplayName Attribute on top of the controller. My main need is to set a nickname for the controllers of When I get all the controllers, I can access the nickname in addition to the original name.

One of several controllers :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[DisplayName("Test Name")]
public class RolesController : ControllerBase
{
 ...
}
```

my method :

```
public IList<ActionAndControllerName> AreaAndActionAndControllerNamesList()
    {
        var endpoints = endpointSources
        .SelectMany(es => es.Endpoints)
        .OfType<RouteEndpoint>();
        var output = endpoints.Select(
            e =>
            {
                var controller = e.Metadata
                    .OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()
                    .FirstOrDefault();
               
                return new
                {
                    Controller = controller.ControllerName,  
                    ControllerDisplayName = controller.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()?.DisplayName,   
                };
            }
```

But returns a null(ControllerDisplayName ). What needs to change?

Comment: You use reflection to get attributes, but I have no idea why you would ever want to do this for a controller, it makes absolutely no sense at all!

Comment: However, I would assume you need to do `e.MetaData.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>().ControllerTypeInfo.Attributes` or similar.

Comment: @DavidG : To implement dynamic policies

Comment: @DavidG : please explain more

Comment: `RolesController` inherits `ControllerBase` which _is not_ a `RouteEndpoint`, so the parent query with `.OfType<RouteEndpoint>()` will not contain the `RolesController` class.

Comment: Hi @farshidazizi, any update?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your `endpointSources`, but here is a working demo to get the controller name and Display Name:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var controllerlist = asm.GetTypes()
        .Where(type => typeof(ControllerBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        .Select(type => type.GetTypeInfo())
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Controller = x.Name,
            ControllerDisplayName = x.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()?.DisplayName

        }).ToList();
```

Result:

[image]